# spring-tool: the package of 3.6.2 is not useful on linux

Tags: spring

I am using mint linux, and I tried many time by re-download the file, and unzip. but it always throw the following error.what's wrong with the package?

```
$ gunzip spring-tool-suite-3.6.2.RELEASE-e4.4.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz 

gzip: spring-tool-suite-3.6.2.RELEASE-e4.4.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz: invalid compressed data--format violated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to download and unzip that file with no problem.

This is the URL I used to download the file:
http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.2/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.2.RELEASE-e4.4.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

The md5 hash for my file is:
$ md5sum spring-tool-suite-3.6.2.RELEASE-e4.4.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
d2ee324ab22bdafef934276967a0dbf8  spring-tool-suite-3.6.2.RELEASE-e4.4.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

Would be good to compare hashes to be sure that your download was not corrupt.